# Trac plugin with graphical representation of Milestones and Tickets

Tags: plugins, trac

Do you use any trac plugin to represent graphically the roadmap with the various milestones and tickets ? If so, which one ?

I find the view of active tickets really blur.
I would like a tree-like representation of my various milestones with the tickets attached, a kind of complete map of my project.

I've seen the Gantt plugin is no longer maintained.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really use anything myself, but have you seen the trac-hacks website?

I think there is a project that provides a bunch of Agile viewing reports, etc (sadly I can't remember the name of it and my DNS is dead so I can't search :P) but I think searching for 'agile trac plugin' should get you there.

It's free, and it looked quite nice.

-- edit

This is what I'm talking about : http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AgiloForScrumPlugin

Answer (score 3):

You might find the [TRAC Itteco](https://github.com/itteco/IttecoTracPlugin) plugin interesting. I would have used it if my trac had more than two frequent users :-)

<strike>[Some screenshots][2]</strike>

<strike>One image shows nice visualization of milestones and their user stories:</strike>

(edit: struck out dead links, unfortunately the new location on github has no more screenshots)